# How to contact Sendgrid support if I can't log in?

Tags: sendgrid

Just registered on SendGrid. Can't log in (Your username or password is invalid message) using the email address and password OR username and password I registered with. Reset password emails are never sent. The support site insists I have to log in in order to contact support, even if I pick one of the options under the "I can't log in" menu.

The only other links on the page mention the "Stack Overflow Collective" and - even though I think it's wildly inappropriate, that seems to be my only option. This is **NOT** an awe-inspiring experience so far.

So... uhm... how do I contact support so I can log into my Sendgrid account?

Comment: Faced the same issue about a year ago. The only thing I could do was to use another account created with my personal email. I found this form, where you can put your email and a description. I have not tried so I don't know if they get back to you but maybe it can help. https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/requests/new/submit

Comment: If you just registered, maybe your registration didn't go through? Did you try creating an account using the same email address?